# Android: How to change Relative Layout to Scroll Layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

Hello i have an Relative Layout in Android, with EditTexts, TextViews, one Spinner and RadioButtons. It's a lot of things for only one screen, so i need to change for a ScrolView. When i try add the line  in the first line and  on the last Row, I have problems.

How can i add a scroll on my screen without lose all the layout I  built so far?

Answer (score 1):

> so i need to change for a ScrolView

You do not need to *change* "for a ScrolView". You need to *wrap* your `RelativeLayout` in a `ScrollView`.

> How can i add a scroll on my screen without lose all the layout I built so far?

Put a `ScrollView` around your `RelativeLayout`:

```
<ScrollView>   
    <RelativeLayout> 
               <!-- existing stuff here -->
    </RelativeLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare has said, you can just wrap your current layout with a `ScrollView`.

Just keep in mind that a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) must have only one child.